# What's the cheapest way to detect vibration with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensor, components, piezoelectricity

What's the cheapest way to detect vibration with Arduino?

What's the vibration sensor that I need?

I want to detect PING PONG NET vibration and light on led if touched.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Depending of what you wanna do, maybe it's not necessary to use a vibration sensor.

Comment: @Daniel See edit.

Comment: Final result here: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/arduino-ping-pong-net-sensor-part-1/

Comment: Great work!!! @elp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piezo sensors are cheap, reliable and designed for the purpose you suggest - [arduino tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Knock)

In the uk, [bitsbox](http://www.bitsbox.co.uk/sensors.html#sound) has one for 75p. You can probably find others cheaper, or salvage from electronic toys.

EDIT following poster's clarification of use:
Sound is vibration through the air, I see no reason why a piezo sensor cannot accomplish what you suggest, but the form factor may not be ideal for fixing to ping pong nets! I think [a flex sensor](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8606) would be more suitable, sewn into the top of the net.

Comment: Can i use piezo to detect if the ball touch or not the pingpong net? Or it detect only vibration sound?

Answer (score 2):

A cheap vibration sensor such as SW-18010P consisting of a fine spring wire coiled around a rigid wire in a sealed package may well be sensitive enough. They act as a momentary switch contact when jolted, and cost a few pennies.

Answer (score 1):

An optical or magnetic sensor mounted mid net, bottom edge might be a good way to acomplish this.  Might also detect vibrations in the table, as might any sensor.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in how to create a simple circuit using a piezo element and Arduino Uno that can detect vibration with high sensitivity http://davidhoulding.blogspot.com/2014/11/advanced-high-sensitivity-vibration.html
Have fun.